# Git. Организация работы

Tags: git, hosting, localhost

Подскажите, как правильно организовать работу с git для проекта.

Над проектом работаю только я, но с разных компов (дом, офис). Сайт находится на хостинге.

Хотелось бы получить следующее:

1. Разработка на локальной машине
2. Сохранение изменений и выталкивание на test.site.com
3. Тестирование на test.site.com. Все ок. Выталкивание на site.com

Если можно, то с командами в терминале.

P.S. уже пробовал реализовать это, но получилась какая то муть.

Comment: clone -> (edit -> add -> pull -> commit -> push)*

Comment: а клонировать то что?

Comment: > а клонировать то что?
Репозиторий на удаленном хостинге.

Answer (score 2):

Даю ответ на свой же вопрос:

1. Создаю репозиторий на сервере командой 
   `git init`
2. Клонирую на локальную машину репозиторий `git clone username@hostname:/path/to/project/`
3. Работаю в локальной копии, затем как обычно все

   ```
   git add /path/to/files
   git commit -m "Message bla bla"
   git pull origin master
   git push origin master
   ```

Теперь наши изменения отправлены на сервер (хостинг), но на сервере у нас осталась предыдущая версия, которая в данный момент и работает при переходе на сайт.

Необходимо на сервере выполнить команду, которая восстановит первоначальную версию (которую мы уже подменили при пуше)

```
git reset --hard
```

После этого изменения с локальной машины доступны на продакшене

Answer (score 1):

Для второго пункта можно использовать `hooks`.

я делаю примерно так на вебсервере:

**hooks/post-update**

```
branch=`basename "$1"`;
touch /var/spool/www-publish/4update/$branch
```

в rc.local зарегал скрипт **`su - www-data -c /var/spool/www-publish/publishwait &`**

```
#!/bin/sh
while :;do

        inotifywait -t 10 /var/spool/www-publish/4update/
        find /var/spool/www-publish/4update/ -type f|while read a; do
                 rm $a
                 /var/spool/www-publish/4update/publish_test.sh `basename $a`
                # тут был запрос на обновление данных багтрекером
        done
done
```

**/var/spool/www-publish/4update/publish_test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh 
branch=$1;
cd /var/spool/www-publish/git/
git checkout $branch
git fetch --all --force
git reset --hard origin/$branch
git pull  --force  origin $branch
cd ..
rsync --exclude .git/  --exclude protected/config/local.php -ra --delete -f 'P /images/' -f 'P /images/**' -f 'P /files/' -f 'P /files/**'  git/ /var/www/$branch.site/
exit
```

таким образом в `/var/spool/www-publish/git/` должен быть клонированный репозиторий вашего проекта с правильно прописанным `origin`, права на запись - `www-data`, для каждой ветки прописал `vhost` (можно и чтобы оно их автоматом находило) `local.php` - это конфиг уникальный для ветки, делается вручную при создании ветки (опять-же можно в принципе автоматизировать)

Answer (score 0):

Всё-таки `git` это не `ftp`, и просто так на удалённый хост вы ничего не сможете вытолкнуть. Для того, чтобы куда-то выталкивать, там должен стоять сервер. Вы, конечно, можете попробовать установить `gitolite`, но дело это не такое простое, а вы, как мне показалось, не особо любите сам разбираться. Советую вам завести репозиторий на одном из сайтов, предоставляющих git hosting, например bitbucket, unfuddle или gitorious, которые позволяют бесплатно хранить приватные репозитории.
Вытолкнув код туда, вы можете настроить свой test.site.com таким образом, чтобы он мог делать с вашего git хостинга pull.

Либо можете посмотреть в сторону heroku и аналогичных (в зависимости от вашего языка программирования), которые совмещают обычный хостинг и git хостинг, но там вас тоже ждёт немало сюрпризов.

Могу посоветовать разрабатывать локально, а для деплоя кода на сервер использовать какую-то специализированную вещь, например Capistrano. Она позволит не только обновить код, но и выполнять дополнительные команды, такие как обновление схемы БД и рестарт сервера.

Comment: я выше по моему показал пример кастомного деплоя, что сложного ?